# How do you count a range of numbers with specific text?

Tags: microsoft-excel

A few days ago I received the Excel update and a few features changed so I am unsure why this method does not work anymore.

[image]

I am trying to count ranges with specific text within the cell regardless of position. This can usally be done with:

> =COUNTIF(range,"(asterisk)text(asterisk)")

Sadly, this method does not work anymore as shown in the output. I have also attempted removing the quotes, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard works with text strings but not with numbers. One option would be have a separate column with the text equivalent of the numbers in C2:C4. For example in D2, enter `=C2&""` to create a string version of the number. Copy that formula to D3 and D4, then change the COUNTIF formula to

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D4,"816*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards with numbers do not work in `COUNTIF`, but there are other formulas you can use.

For example, to count all the entries in a range that start with `816`, try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(ISNUMBER(1/1/(FIND("816",myRange)=1))))
```

[image]

If you want to find `816` no matter where it is in the string, then just remove the `=1` from the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(ISNUMBER(1/1/FIND("816",myRange))))
```